# Bluetooth gamepad sleeps after a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, games, input-devices, gamepad, joystick

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with RetroArch and a correctly paired 8BitDo Bluetooth gamepad. Everything works fine, except that after a few idle seconds the controller sleeps, causing the next button press to be missed, because it will simply wake it up again. Are there any Bluetooth default power saving settings I could try to disable to prevent this?

Edit:
RetroArch is the official AppImage downloaded directly from: https://retroarch.com/?page=platforms

Comment: Hello. Do not think you have given all the info. How was this game installed?

Comment: I've just updated the question with more details.